# How do I conditionally compile environment-specific template in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have Angular 5 application with several environments (dev, qa, customer1, customer2, etc.). Using `environment.xxx.ts` I get runtime configuration variables with no problem. However, I can't conditionally include a template during compilation. That is, I would like to have something like that:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-hello',
    templateUrl: `hello.component.${environment.client}.html`
})
```

where `environment.client` is provided by `environment.customer1.ts`.

Maybe it's a bigger question - how can I control template or stylesheet in Component's metadata.

**NOTE 1**: I realize that soon we will get Ivy renderer that will allow to combine AOT and JIT compilers; but I am not trying to load the template dynamically - only compile the right template depending on the environment.

**NOTE 2**: I tried `dotenv`, but it seems to work the same way: it gives me control of the environment variables *at runtime*, but doesn't help to choose the right file for compilation.

Comment: FWIW, this approach works for me in Angular 13.1.

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a while since you posted this question, but we have the same issue and I just resolved it by using different modules.

I have a module (customer-components.module.ts) which decides which customer components are included depending on the enviornment.

```
const customerComponents = [CustomerModule];
const defaultComponents = [DefaultModule];

// I just realised functions are not working in aot
// not the best way if there are lots of customers which is the case for us. 
// i will see if i can find a nicer way to decide on the components. but the mechanisim works

const exports = env.customer === 'customer1' ? customerComponents : defaultComponents; 

 @NgModule({
  imports: [
    CustomerModule,
    DefaultModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: getExports()
})
export class CustomerComponentsModule {}
```

All customer specific components are bundled within one customer-module. In this example customer-module may only declares and exports the navigation.component. The default-module declares and exports the same components. Important is the fact, that the selectors in each component are identical. This means, in both modules: customer-module and default-module, there the navigation-component have the same selector (app-navigation).

Now I can import the customer-module whereever I want, e.g. in the app-module. and use  in the app.component.html and the environment directs which navigation component is being exported and used within the app.component.